# Which of the Superman scenes of Justice League are from Henry Cavill's CGI-removed mustache?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, justice-league

Henry Cavill's CGI-removed mustache in *Justice League* was one of the most infamously talked-about things, and it has already been covered in [another question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82949/why-did-warner-bros-spend-25-million-to-cgi-out-henry-cavills-mustache).

But I want to know if there is a cohesive list of scenes with the CGI-removed mustache in the film?

Answer (score 4):

All the Joss Whedon directed scenes

1. Superman talking to kids , cellphone footage .
2. From the Part of the fight where Superman picks up Batman , upto that point it was directed by Zack Snyder .
3. Scenes in the Kent farm .
4. Parts of Final fight where superman shows up and wits out funny lines .
5. Superman vs Flash race scene .

Speaking frankly , this covers most of superman's screen-time in the movie .